# Sum the seconds between two datetime columns for multiple records in Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Is it possible to use an Ecto query to sum the total number of seconds between two naive_datetime columns?

In the example below, the running time of each item in `selected_items` is the number of seconds between `created_at` and `completed_at`.

I would like to create a query that returns the total running time for all records in `selected_items`.

```
total_seconds = Repo.one(from item in selected_items,
      select: sum(***Seconds between item.completed_at and item.created_at***)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use [`Ecto.Query.dynamic/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2):

```
select = dynamic([item], item.completed_at - item.created_at)
from item in selected_items, select: sum(^select)
```

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but I get an error: `** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) 'item.completed_at() - item.created_at()' is not a valid query expression.` I think I might habe to try and use a fragment to implement a DATE_PART postgreSQL query.

Comment: This is quite strange. Does your schema define these?

Comment: Of course with a fragment you might do everything in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, they are defined in the schema. It seems that subtraction is not part of the Ecto query API: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html

Comment: [No way](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2-examples). The nearly same code works for me in my project.

Comment: So strange. If I do: `select = dynamic([item], item.completed_at > item.created_at)
from item in selected_items, where: ^select` it compiles fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot try it out here at the moment, but would you mind to try to move `sum()` inside `dynamic` definition?

Comment: Same compilation error with `sum` inside the `dynamic` definition. I think the example [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2-examples) is subtracting 1 from a predefined variable, rather than a database column.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to acheive what I needed to using a fragment.

```js
total_seconds = Repo.one(from item in selected_items,
      select: sum(fragment("? - ?", item.completed_at, item.created_at))
```